# How to use Java doulbe colon operator (::) in a multi-step sentence correctly?

Tags: java

I have a POJO class `News` with a method `getAuthor()`, that returns another POJO, `Author`. `Author` itself has a getter `getRate()`, this one returns `int` value. But I can't just make `Comparator` for `News` using double colons. I mean something like this (but, of course, that doesn't work):

```
Set<News> sortedNews = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(News::getAuthor::getRate));
```

So the question is, how to write this correctly.

Comment: you can't use method reference (`::`) more than once in a row unfortunately. However `News.getAuthor()::getRate` should be possible

Comment: Just use a lambda to return the value you want to compare by.

Comment: @j-asgarov No, suddenly, that doesn't work too for JDK 17.

Comment: @shawn Yes, it seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language doesn't allow you do it. Use a normal lambda expression.

```
Comparator.comparingInt(news -> news.getAuthor().getRate())
```